# Perpendicular line creation is not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, line

I run the transect tool with 90 degree required parameter to draw perpendicular lines from a line. I got the output but when I measured the angle it is not showing as 95 degree.

What will be the error?

[image]

Comment: Do you use a projected CRS?

Comment: The working in GCS and I didn't project anything. Could it be the error?

Comment: In which CRS is your line?

Comment: Hi, just checked with PCS now I am getting perpendicular lines. Earlier it was in 4326.

Comment: Please place answer and I will mark it.

Comment: What is PCS ? ...

Comment: Projected Coordinate System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your layer is in a geographic CRS ( coordinate reference system) like EPSG:4326, reproject it to a projected CRS like EPSG:3857.

Comment: Web Mercator is safe for angles, but not distances, so I'd be careful recommending it without a caveat.

Comment: @Vince Would a UTM projection be better in this case?

Comment: @wingnut It depends on the extent; a custom equal-area projection might be a better fit (if there isn't a ready-made one available)